# pandas read_sql_query list object has no attribute keys

Tags: python, pandas, connection-string, trino

I am trying to run a simple query on a trino engine using pandas `read_sql_query`.

```
params = ('6017cef554df4124274ef36d', '62ea18d1d931811975150c4b')
con = Engine(trino://rakesh%40xyz.com:***@anc.xyc.com:***/ktm/public)
sql = 'SELECT * FROM glue.views.tbl_abc where col_1 = %s AND col_2 = %s'

try:
    pd.read_sql_query(text(sql), con=con, params=params) << NOTE:: with text(sql)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Here with `text(sql)` gives `'list' object has no attribute 'keys'` error

And with `pd.read_sql_query(sql, con=con, params=params)`, i.e without `text()`
gives

```
TrinoUserError(type=USER_ERROR, name=SYNTAX_ERROR, message="line 1:102: mismatched input '='. Expecting: <predicate>", query_id=20220803__ydfdf)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You create your engine, but you don't connect to it.

```py
engine = Engine("trino://rakesh%40xyz.com:***@anc.xyc.com:***/ktm/public")
con = engine.connect()
```